# Save a list of lists in different CSV files

Tags: python, list, csv

I have 1 big list, that is 2 lists of lists, grouped by 1st item.

I wish to save each group of lists, in different CSV file ('|').

**This is the big list:**

```
[
 [
  ['2-MG', '3_4_5', '1110', '200', 'xxw', 'sder', 'key_3', '01032021', '31032021', 'sder', ''],
  ['2-MG', '2_3_4', '1110', 'C-200', '08032021', '2', '2', '123', ''],
  ['2-MG', '3_4_5', '1110', 'C-200', '08032021', '3', '2', '123', ''],
  ['2-MG', '2_3_4', '08032021', '1115', '5', 'xxe', 'sdf', '0', 'xxe', '5', 'xxe', '', ''],
  ['2-MG', '3_4_5', '08032021', '1115', '6', 'xxz', 'csd', '0', 'xxz', '6', 'xxz', '', '']
  ],
 [
  ['1-MG', '1_2_3', '1110', '200', 'xxr', 'wer', 'key_1', '01032021', '31032021', 'wer', ''],
  ['1-MG', '2_3_4', '1110', '200', 'xxv', 'cad', 'key_2', '01032021', '31032021', 'cad', ''], 
  ['1-MG', '1_2_3', '1110', 'C-200', '07032021', '1', '2', '123', ''], 
  ['1-MG', '2_3_4', '1110', 'C-200', '07032021', '2', '2', '123', ''], 
  ['1-MG', '3_4_5', '1110', 'C-200', '07032021', '3', '2', '123', ''], 
  ['1-MG', '1_2_3', '1110', 'C-200', '08032021', '1', '2', '123', ''], 
  ['1-MG', '1_2_3', '07032021', '1115', '1', 'xxr', 'wer', '0', 'xxr', '1', 'xxr', '', ''], 
  ['1-MG', '2_3_4', '07032021', '1115', '2', 'xxv', 'cad', '0', 'xxv', '2', 'xxv', '', ''], 
  ['1-MG', '3_4_5', '07032021', '1115', '3', 'xxw', 'sder', '0', 'xxw', '3', 'xxw', '', ''], 
  ['1-MG', '1_2_3', '08032021', '1115', '4', 'xxt', 'dse', '0', 'xxt', '4', 'xxt', '', '']
  ]
 ]
```

**This is my code:**

```py
g = []

for i in biglist:
    for j in i:
        k = j[0]
        #j.pop(0)
        with open(f'{k}.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter='|')
                #print(j)
                #print(k)
                g.append(j)
                writer.writerows(g)
```

**This is my expected result:**

```
1st file named '2-MG.csv'

2-MG|3_4_5|1110|200|xxw|sder|key_3|01032021|31032021|sder|
2-MG|2_3_4|1110|C-200|08032021|2|2|123|
2-MG|3_4_5|1110|C-200|08032021|3|2|123|
2-MG|2_3_4|08032021|1115|5|xxe|sdf|0|xxe|5|xxe||
2-MG|3_4_5|08032021|1115|6|xxz|csd|0|xxz|6|xxz||


2nd file named '1-MG.csv'

1-MG|1_2_3|1110|200|xxr|wer|key_1|01032021|31032021|wer|
1-MG|2_3_4|1110|200|xxv|cad|key_2|01032021|31032021|cad|
1-MG|1_2_3|1110|C-200|07032021|1|2|123|
1-MG|2_3_4|1110|C-200|07032021|2|2|123|
1-MG|3_4_5|1110|C-200|07032021|3|2|123|
1-MG|1_2_3|1110|C-200|08032021|1|2|123|
1-MG|1_2_3|07032021|1115|1|xxr|wer|0|xxr|1|xxr||
1-MG|2_3_4|07032021|1115|2|xxv|cad|0|xxv|2|xxv||
1-MG|3_4_5|07032021|1115|3|xxw|sder|0|xxw|3|xxw||
1-MG|1_2_3|08032021|1115|4|xxt|dse|0|xxt|4|xxt||
```

Let me know if you have any doubts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over iterating and writing every item of every sublist out to its own file.

Just write each sublist out:

```py
import csv

big_list = [[
    ['2-MG', '3_4_5', '1110', '200', 'xxw', 'sder', 'key_3', '01032021',
     '31032021', 'sder', ''],
    ['2-MG', '2_3_4', '1110', 'C-200', '08032021', '2', '2', '123', ''],
    ['2-MG', '3_4_5', '1110', 'C-200', '08032021', '3', '2', '123', ''],
    ['2-MG', '2_3_4', '08032021', '1115', '5', 'xxe', 'sdf', '0', 'xxe', '5',
     'xxe', '', ''],
    ['2-MG', '3_4_5', '08032021', '1115', '6', 'xxz', 'csd', '0', 'xxz', '6',
     'xxz', '', '']], [
    ['1-MG', '1_2_3', '1110', '200', 'xxr', 'wer', 'key_1', '01032021',
     '31032021', 'wer', ''],
    ['1-MG', '2_3_4', '1110', '200', 'xxv', 'cad', 'key_2', '01032021',
     '31032021', 'cad', ''],
    ['1-MG', '1_2_3', '1110', 'C-200', '07032021', '1', '2', '123', ''],
    ['1-MG', '2_3_4', '1110', 'C-200', '07032021', '2', '2', '123', ''],
    ['1-MG', '3_4_5', '1110', 'C-200', '07032021', '3', '2', '123', ''],
    ['1-MG', '1_2_3', '1110', 'C-200', '08032021', '1', '2', '123', ''],
    ['1-MG', '1_2_3', '07032021', '1115', '1', 'xxr', 'wer', '0', 'xxr', '1',
     'xxr', '', ''],
    ['1-MG', '2_3_4', '07032021', '1115', '2', 'xxv', 'cad', '0', 'xxv', '2',
     'xxv', '', ''],
    ['1-MG', '3_4_5', '07032021', '1115', '3', 'xxw', 'sder', '0', 'xxw', '3',
     'xxw', '', ''],
    ['1-MG', '1_2_3', '08032021', '1115', '4', 'xxt', 'dse', '0', 'xxt', '4',
     'xxt', '', '']]]

for sub_lst in big_list:
    f_name = sub_lst[0][0]
    with open(f'{f_name}.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter='|')
        writer.writerows(sub_lst)
```

---

1-MG.csv

```
1-MG|1_2_3|1110|200|xxr|wer|key_1|01032021|31032021|wer|
1-MG|2_3_4|1110|200|xxv|cad|key_2|01032021|31032021|cad|
1-MG|1_2_3|1110|C-200|07032021|1|2|123|
1-MG|2_3_4|1110|C-200|07032021|2|2|123|
1-MG|3_4_5|1110|C-200|07032021|3|2|123|
1-MG|1_2_3|1110|C-200|08032021|1|2|123|
1-MG|1_2_3|07032021|1115|1|xxr|wer|0|xxr|1|xxr||
1-MG|2_3_4|07032021|1115|2|xxv|cad|0|xxv|2|xxv||
1-MG|3_4_5|07032021|1115|3|xxw|sder|0|xxw|3|xxw||
1-MG|1_2_3|08032021|1115|4|xxt|dse|0|xxt|4|xxt||
```

---

2-MG.csv

```
2-MG|3_4_5|1110|200|xxw|sder|key_3|01032021|31032021|sder|
2-MG|2_3_4|1110|C-200|08032021|2|2|123|
2-MG|3_4_5|1110|C-200|08032021|3|2|123|
2-MG|2_3_4|08032021|1115|5|xxe|sdf|0|xxe|5|xxe||
2-MG|3_4_5|08032021|1115|6|xxz|csd|0|xxz|6|xxz||
```

---

Edit to include dropping first element from every sublist:

```py
for sub_lst in big_list:
    f_name = sub_lst[0][0]
    with open(f'{f_name}.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter='|')
        writer.writerows([r[1:] for r in sub_lst])
```

Comment: Thanks man. But what if I need to drop the 1st column ('1-MG' & '2-MG') ?